# What is the easiest way to dump a REGION of memory in IDA pro?

Tags: ida, idapython

I'm facing a problem that i need to dump a large region of memory with IDA pro

using xdbg its easily done by going to memory map tab and just dumping a region, how can i do this in IDA pro? for example dump from address x to y

I tried to use a simple IDApython script but if the size is large  IDA will just crash (I'm dumping a large region while remotely debugging a windows kernel)

```
filename = AskFile(1, "*.bin", "Output file name")
address = startAddress
size = 0xFFFFFF
dbgr = True
with open(filename, "wb") as out:
    data = GetManyBytes(address, size, use_dbg=dbgr)
    out.write(data)
```

Comment: Did you try to dump the region by parts?

Comment: @ws No, do you mean put a loop and split the region into pieces?

Comment: yes, definitely

Comment: @ws yes this is i actually did at the end and found out there was a problematic region in the kernel for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without scripting:

1. Select the range:

Go to start of the area, press <kbd>Alt+L</kbd>, go to the end

2. Edit, Export data (or <kbd>Shift+E</kbd>)
3. pick "raw bytes" and enter filename in the Outpuf File field.

With scripting:

```
idc.savefile(filename, 0, startAddress, size)
```